# How to mention an uncertain object/thing in English?

Tags: word-usage

I want to know how to mention an uncertain object, like X country.

e.g. I want to go to a **certain** country no matter where it is because I just need to go out right now.

I found a [Question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/252054/difference-between-certain-specific-and-particular) on this website.
It seems I can use a **certain** country to infer a country that is not specific or particular but it's just a country in the context.

1. Is it correct?
2. Or I should use **a** country instead?
3. Or there's no comparable usage in English?

---

More example in other languages,

In other languages, such as Japanese or Mandarin, we use あの or 某個 to refer to an object that's not a specific one but belongs to the group of the object.
That is to say, あの or 某個 often implies the object that the speaker mentioned has specific meanings in the dialogue.

---

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean: “I want to go to a different country, I don’t care where it is. I just need to get away right now.”  Or “I just want to go somewhere-  anywhere.”

Comment: The indefinite pronouns can help here.

Comment: I want to go abroad.

Comment: 'Imply', not 'infer'. And ' I want to go to a certain country no matter where it is because ...' sounds most unnatural. 'No matter where it is' here defaults to 'it doesn't matter which' while 'certain' means 'I have just one in mind'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must go to **another** country.

> Another = a different person or thing
>
> She's finished with that boyfriend and found herself another (one).
>
> ”Do you want to exchange this toaster for another (one) or do you want your money back?”
>
> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/another)

Notice how the examples refer to a different but otherwise undefined example selected from the same class of things, just as in your specification.

*certain* does not have the feeling of *otherwise undefined*, instead drawing attention to a particular example.

> Certain = particular but not named or described:
>
> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/certain)